# Can't deploy my changes to the GitHub pages

Tags: npm, web-deployment, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my changes on the GitHub pages but unfortunately got the following error, during the execution of `npm run deploy`.

```
> 2048@1.0.0 deploy /home/yaroslav/Desktop/lab/2048
> gh-pages -b master -d build

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/yaroslav/Desktop/lab/2048/build'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! 2048@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the 2048@1.0.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/yaroslav/.npm/_logs/2020-05-09T12_02_20_500Z-debug.log
```

The same error if a command for `depoloy` is `gh-pages -d build`.

Comment: It says that the build directory does not exist, does it? By the way, try to delete the node_modules and run `npm install` again, hope It helps

Comment: I don't even know why does `build/` should exists. Will try.

Comment: It still does not work.

Comment: As the error says you can check this log file `/home/yaroslav/.npm/_logs/2020-05-09T12_02_20_500Z-debug.log` for more info

Answer (score 0):

So, I haven't found any answers to this particular problem and just deployed my application using netlify in a few clicks.